# Make: Compiling only one .c file though i modify the header file which is included in two .c files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two .c files and one .h file which is included in both .c files.

I have make file :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

OBJ = hellofunc.o hellomake.o

DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

-include $(DEPS)

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) $<
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

I modified hellomake.h header file and then ran above make file. It is compiling only the first file which is assigned to DEPS variable, Which is hellofunc.c

FYI, When i change the order of DEPS variable it is compiling hellomake.o , Seems like make is only picking first file assigned to DEPS variable.
Is there anything wrong in my makefile.. Please help.

Comment: You have not declared any dependency on `hellomake.h` so of course Make ignores it.

Comment: @tripleee, Can you please give brief answer by updating my make file? I am new to make

Comment: I am including both hellomake.d , hellofunc.d files using include directive.. That should work right?

Comment: I think this question should not have been marked as duplicate of a the question cited by those who voted to close. This one makes use of automatic dependency generation. Manually adding header files to the prerequisites should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

As @tripleee noted in the comments, `make` will by default build the first target it encounters.  Since the `include` files are included directly, as if they were cut-and-pasted in place, the first target in the first `.d` file (which I'm guessing you'll find to be `hellofunc.c`) is the first target that `make` encounters, so that's what `make` aims to build.

If you move the `include` line to the end of the file, then the first target in the file will be `hellomake`, and so that's the target `make` will attempt to build by default.

Meta remark: if you can, I'd say it's better to avoid this pattern of depending on `.d` files, and instead aim to express sufficiently many of the dependencies ‘by hand’ directly in the makefile.  Doing it this `.d` way does work (ie, I'm not saying what you're doing is wrong) and appears to be labour-saving, but in my experience it tends to be a little brittle, partly because if you don't have the `.d` files to hand then you suddenly have zero dependencies.  In order to have the `.d` files to hand, you'll have to check them in to your code repository (you *are* using a repository, aren't you?), but that will mean they'll frequently be trivially out of date, and... it can turn into a bit of a mess.

Comment: If one .c file includes n number of header files .We can t specify them in our make files right? It looks bit ugly. Is there any simple way to handle this?

Comment: I disagree with the discussion about auto-generated prerequisites in the last paragraph above.  They are actually perfectly reliable when done correctly (unfortunately because make is a generic tool, and not a tool specifically for working with C/C++ programs, doing it right takes a bit of work).  Handling prerequisites by hand is fine in simple situations but it's simply untenable in any moderate to large program.  See http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ for a discussion of how to do auto-dependency correctly (even if all .d files are removed!)

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the opposing point of view, and the useful link. The 'a bit of work' and the length of that page, illustrate what I regard as the downside, and why I think of this approach as 'brittle' (in my experience) rather than wrong. I've tried multiple ways of managing this, over the years, with and without automake (and I'll read your page carefully), and concluded that make is one of those systems where 'mostly correct and readable/maintainable' is better than 'completely correct but write-only'. This is probably a style/taste issue, in the end.

Comment: If you have 10 files with simple prerequisites, it's fine to list things by hand.  In projects I work on we have over 1500 source files and over 1700 header files across many directories (and this is nowhere near a "large" project, really).  It's C++ so there is a *lot* of recursive header file inclusion and there is simply no way to manage that by hand.  The real problem is that if you forget to add a prerequisite to your makefile then your program can break in subtle and hard to understand ways.  It's not just a compile error.  An unreliable makefile is often WORSE than no makefile.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: considered [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist)'s comment and [blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) about separate recipe for `.d` files.

You could tell make how to generate the `.d` files with a separate rule instead of putting this in another recipe (but see the above mentioned blog post for several reasons for not doing so).

And you should probably tell make that your default goal is `hellomake`:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := hellomake

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

OBJ = hellofunc.o hellomake.o

DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

-include $(DEPS)

%.d: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $@ $<

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

And it would probably be even better if you were letting make find the source files and deduce the rest:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := hellomake

CC     := gcc
CFLAGS := -I.
SRCS   := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
DEPS   := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC))

-include $(DEPS)

%.d: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $@ $<

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Finally, following [MadScientist's advices](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), a better, more efficient, less prone to failures solution could be:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := hellomake

CC     := gcc
CFLAGS := -I.
SRCS   := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS   := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
DEPS   := $(wildcard $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRC)))

include $(DEPS)

%.o: %.c %.d
    $(CC) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $*.Td $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    mv -f $*.Td $*.d && touch $@

hellomake: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: %.d
```

Comment: Ohh Got it. Thanks! Do we have any tutorials or articles for "-MM -MT" dependency options ? Can you please share if any ?

Comment: Actually creating a separate recipe for `.d` files leads to a lot of unpleasant side-effects.  The new modern (and best) method for creating prerequisite files is to create them as part of building the object file, not in a separate rule.  See the blog post I lined to in comments above for a full discussion.

Comment: BTW, It didnt worked. I copied same make file content above. Still its comping only one .c file.

Comment: @santosh: are you sure both files include this header file? And did you check the content of the `.d` files to verify that this header file is really listed as a dependency?

Comment: Yeah, I verified. I am including header file in both .c files. And .d files also has header file listed in it.

Comment: @santosh: honestly, I do not understand how this is possible. If your dependencies are correctly listing this header file for both object files and you change the header file, make should consider the object files as out-dated and rebuild them. Did you manually  compare the last  modification times of the modified header file and of the object files? Could it be kind of NFS time skew?

Comment: @MadScientist: Yes, you're right, of course. Your blog post is extremely interesting and inspiring, thanks. And santosh should probably read it also one day or another. But for this simple hello world example I suspect that a simpler, less efficient but much easier to understand solution is preferable.